# How do define service(or repository) in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I want define a repository without extend JpaRepository or CrudRepository, as follow:

```
@Repository
public interface MyService {
    void method1();
}
```

Now for running app, occur error as follow:

```
Field MyService in com.rasadco.Application required a bean of type 'com.rasadco.MyService' that could not be found.
```

How do I define a service(or repository) in Spring Boot 1.5.13?

Comment: if you are creating @Repository then u need to extend repository like "JpaRepository"